# Trouble understanding how the global variable is being passed in the depth first search algorithm pseudocode

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I was reading the pseudocode of depth-first-search algorithm below [image: below] . According to the pseudocode, I understand how the global variable within `DFS(G)` is defined but I have trouble understanding how is it possible that the global variable within `DFS(G)` is not being passed into the recursive method `DFS-visit(G, u)` but `time` is being incremented within the recursive method. I tried doing writing the code out like this:

```
class Algo{
     ...

     public void dfs(Graph g){
            ....
            long time = 0;
            // for-loop
                 dfs_visit(g , u);
     }

     public void dfs_visit(Graph G, Vertex u){
          long time = time + 1;
          .....
     }
}
```

And this generates a compilation error in the `dfs-visit(G, u)`:

`error: variable time might not have been initialized
        long time = time + 1;`

I am sensing that I am thinking this in a wrong way but I just do not understand how `time` can be incremented in `dfs-vist` method without being passed as an argument. 
Please help me correct my logic.

Comment: in Java, class names are in `UpperCamelCase` and method names are in `lowerCamelCase` you have it backwards and makes people that might help you gouge their eyes out!

Comment: ok. Sorry about that. I will edit that

Comment: before you attempt to write DFS in java, I would suggest to get acquainted with language syntax first. Currently you are stuck at compilation issues, forget about complex logic.

Comment: Just to clarify:  I understand the algorithm and you guys are right that  I need to learn the language syntax. This question is actually about understanding how to define global variable in Java. Sorry about that guys.

Comment: there is no such thing as global variables in Java

Comment: So I would like to kindly ask what would you call it in this case ? I mean should I call  `time`  an instance variable in this case ? I just want to learn from experts in here. Hope that I am not annoying anyone in here. If I do, I apologise for that.

Answer (score 0):

`time` seems to be a global variable in the pseudo-code, you may want to introduce it as a field (i.e. class global) variable instead of a local variable.

```
class Algo{
    long time = 0;
    ....
```